# ActiveRecord Associations: Any gotchas if has_many WITHOUT corresponding belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

A phone has many messages.

An email address has many messages.

A message either belongs to a phone, email, or neither. The `belongs_to` association is optional.

The following associations seem to work fine for these relationships:

- Phone model `has_many :messages`
- Email model `has_many :messages`
- Message model does NOT have `belongs_to :phones, :email`

Is this okay or is there some proper way to specify a "can_belong_to" relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is completely correct unidirectional relation. Using both is sometimes called "curcular dependency" by some purists and may cause problems when using [validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated).

From the other side using only `has_many :messages` may be not enough when you want retrieve phone information from one message. Generally it is matter of convenience.

Comment: yeah we found out that without "belongs_to" we cannot say in a view @message.phone.username   Thanks for the quick confirmation!

Answer (score 1):

The model with the `belongs_to` associations holds the foreign keys (e.g. `messages` table would have `phone_id` and `email_id` columns).

The `belongs_to` association combined with `has_many` lets you easily access associated records:

```
phone.messages
message.phone
```

So without the `belongs_to` and FK columns, the `has_many` association isn't very useful.

It seems like in this case you may want a many-to-many relationship such as [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) as a message can have many recipients.